# Which zlib functions are compatible with WinZip?

Tags: c, algorithm, compression, gzip

Using `deflate()` I was unable to open the zipped file using WinZip. Are the gz() the only ones compatible with WinZip? or is there some sort of mode I must call `deflate()` with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from http://www.zlib.net/zlib_faq.html

> Can zlib handle .zip archives?
>
> Not by
>   itself, no. See the directory
>   contrib/minizip in the zlib
>   distribution.

Answer (score 4):

zlib only implements the used compression algorithm, not the ZIP file structure. You need to parse the ZIP file yourself and then you can decompress the file chunks with zlib.

Note, that there is no gzip header in the file chunks, so you need to do a "raw inflate". Check the zlib documentation for more details.